# month name in localized date format getting mangled in a rails 3.1.3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have these date/time formats specified in my config/locales/en.yml file:

```
time:
  formats:
    long_date: "%B %d, %Y"
    medium_date: "%b %d, %Y"
    short_date: "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p"
date:
  formats:
    long_date: "%B %d, %Y"
    medium_date: "%b %d, %Y"
    short_date: "%m/%d/%y"
```

And I'm trying to print a localized date like so in one of my views:

```
<%= l report.created_at, :format => :medium_date %>
```

But the month name is getting oddly mangled, with the resulting output

```
n 13, 2012
```

I get the same output when I use :format => :long_date.

When I use :format => :short_date, though, all is well, and I get:

```
03/13/12 07:53 am
```

I know it is something I did because it was working perfectly just a few days ago. Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

figured this out.  i had this in my en.yml file:

```
en:
  date: "Date"
```

... which of course overwrote the date: key for the date formats!